# How to import Cloudant module to manipulate existing documents via IBM cloud server less function python 3.9 actions?

Tags: python, websphere, action, serverless, cloudant

I am new to Cloud SDK, and I tried to invoke the following action, but I get **error : " stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cloudant'",.**

- ***NOTE**:*
- Console ==>  IBM cloudant python 3.9 SDK: **No module named 'cloudant'"**
- CLI ==> Python 3.86 : **accepted the module without error**
- Question :==> **I need to know how to do it using the CLI.**

If you have a solution please let me know in time. Thank You!!.

````
from cloudant.client import Cloudant
import requests
import json
   

dict = {"COUCH_USERNAME": "--bluemix",
"IAM_API_KEY": "---bluemix"}

 def main(dict):
        client = Cloudant.iam(user_name=dict["COUCH_USERNAME"],
        api_key=dict["IAM_API_KEY"],
        connect=True)
        my_database=client['reviews']
        return my_database.json```
````

Comment: Did you install cloudant?

Comment: Thank you very much, Yes I did. I have used Python 3.7 and it works.  However, it is depreciated on IBM cloud .

Answer (score 0):

> Yes I did. I have used Python 3.7 and it works. However, it is depreciated on IBM cloud

The Python [`cloudant` module](https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant) is EOL and is replaced by the [`ibmcloudant` module](https://github.com/IBM/cloudant-python-sdk/).

As per the [Functions documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-runtimes#migrate_python_environments_3.73.9) the 3.9 runtime contains the new `ibmcloudant` module.

You should migrate your action code to use `ibmcloudant` instead of `cloudant`. If you can't want to migrate your code then you could [force it to use the 3.7 runtime with `--kind python:3.7`](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-runtimes#openwhisk_ref_python_environments) or create a custom 3.9 runtime with the `cloudant` module installed.